# Automating Dialog

Tags: bash, shell, dialog

How can I, via a shell script, automate the dialog utility.

For example:
[image]

I want to be able to select the name I want. The dialog has no hot keys, so I need to be able to "read" the word under the cursor to select it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a job for shell scripts. Shell scripts can call command-line tools, and there are tools like `expect(1)` that can automate interactive command-line tools, but not for something that draws a textmode GUI to the screen. You'd do better to look at the script that calls `dialog(1)` and make it do what you want directly, instead of having it call `dialog`.

Comment: I have no control over the dialog script and I don't have access to the code. But thanks, I agree that it's certainly not the best way to do, but I really have to do it that way, because we have a proxy machine that redirects us to the machine needed.